# show background-image on mouse over

Tags: css

I have the folowing HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="home-block" style="background-color:#464646; background-image:url('wardrobe.jpg')">Wardrobe</a>
<a href="#" class="home-block" style="background-color:#6a0d1f; background-image:url('wine.jpg')">Wine</a>
<a href="#" class="home-block" style="background-color:#291407; background-image:url('coffee.jpg')">Coffee</a>
```

This is the relevant CSS:

```
.home-block {
    background-color: #c2b89c; display: block; height: 180px; line-height:180px;
    text-align: center; font-size: 70px; color:#e2e2e2;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #444; margin-bottom: 20px; background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center; box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #111;
}
```

My result now looks something like this:

[image]

That's OK, but what I really want is the blocks to have a solid color, and only show the image on hover. Like so:

[image]

Please keep in mind that I'm using a responsive design, so the blocks will have a different size and aspect ratio on different screen sizes. That is why I'm using `background-size: cover`. Also this is for a CMS system, so I want the images and colors to be set inline in the HTML, so it will be easily editable and more blocks can be added.

So I basically need a clean solution without absolute positioned elements (because they tend to break if there's no fixed width) to achieve this.

What I have tried is this:

```
.home-block { background: none; }
.home-block:hover { background: inherit }
```

but with no success. I was just about to fix all of this with some lines of jQuery, but I just quickly wanted to check if there is no pure CSS way to achieve this.

Comment: You're looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/R7anj/

Comment: yes, that's the desired result. But as I mentioned, it's really important to me that the backgrounds are set inline in the home-block, so the stylesheets don't need to be updated everytime my client wants to add a new block to the home page.

Comment: what's the difference between updating the stylesheet and the html inline?

Comment: I just realized I could add a `<style>` block after every home-block to set the hover-rule, but that's not very pretty. Might have to do with that though if nobody comes up with a cleaner solution.

Comment: @ Explosion Pills : because it's for a Wordpress site I'm writing, and it's important that the client can add a new block by just copying one in the html and changing the image url. As you might know, in a CMS the html content is saved in a database. The stylesheets aren't, and even if they were, I couldn't expect from my customers to edit the css files themselves. That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: you use responsive design to improve experience on mobile devices - so you should avoid using :hover, as it isn't available on touch devices

Comment: @Stephan valid argument, and I'm aware of it. That's why I will only use the hover effect if the client is not a mobile device. On mobile devices I only show the images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little bit tricky if you need to have `background-image` set inline in HTML. You can't overwrite it easily. What I would try to do is to change `background-position` on hover:

```
.home-block {
    ...
    background-position: 1000px 1000px; // background-image is there but not visible
}
.home-block:hover {
    background-position: center center !important; // make it visible
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2Jbg/

So for normal state you will not see background image but will see backgroud color. On hover you move image back.

Comment: So simple and obvious! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for this very clean solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it's not possible to use the `:hover` pseudo-class inline, which makes it hard to accomplish this inline on a single element.

It is often a bit ugly to use an additional element for the purpose of styling, but at least it is a possible solution to the problem at hand.

```
<div style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200);">
   <div class="home-block">Foo</div>
</div>
```

You could then use something like this in your CSS:

```
.home-block:hover {
    background: transparent;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FA2aC/1/)

This way, you will be able to add new blocks with individual background-images, without updating the stylesheet.

Comment: very nice and ingenious solution. But I think dfsq's solution is just a tiny bit cleaner. you deserve an upvote non the less!

Comment: @dfsq Seeing your solution, I would go for yours though. :) Very smart and not requiring the additional element that my solution requires.

Comment: Now I come to think of it, if I would ever want to implement a mouseover-effect with 2 background-images, this would definitly be the way to go. I'm going to keep this in mind.

Comment: @Jules Yeah, in that case this would probably be the easiest way to go, but for now I agree that dfsq's solution is nicer.